# Disable Required Field Validator based on RadioButton Check

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code should enable to false when radiobutton value ==2. But every time I click Submit button it prompts me with the RequiredFieldValidator for the LastName textbox.

Thank you!

```
 $('#<%= rblIndOrg.ClientID %>').change(function() { 
                if ($('#<%= rblIndOrg.ClientID %> input:checked').val() == "2") { 
                    $('#<%= tbLast_Name.ClientID%>').val(""); 
                    $('#<%= tbLast_Name.ClientID %>').attr("style", "display: none;");
                    $('#lblLast_Name').attr("style", "display: none;"); 
                    document.getElementById("<%=rfv_tbLast_Name.ClientID%>").enabled = false; 
                } 
                else { 
                    $('#<%= tbLast_Name.ClientID %>').attr("style", "display:inline;"); 
                    $('#lblLast_Name').attr("style", "display: block;"); 
                    document.getElementById("<%=rfv_tbLast_Name.ClientID%>").enabled = true; 
                    }
            });
```

Comment: Is the value of radio buttons correct and does the code enter the if-block? Maybe test it with a webbrowser developer tool or simple console.log('value is 2');

Comment: <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblIndOrg" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" CssClass="radioButtonList"
                            RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">Individual</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Organization</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>

Comment: Yes it is. It works for all others not showing the textbox is only when I click Submit because it doesn't pick up the enable false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not just to disable the tbLast_Name but also remove required-attribute (if exists)

```
$('#lblLast_Name').attr("style", "display: none;"); 
$('#lblLast_Name').removeAttr('required');
```

In else block you should add the required-attribyte at first line back again.

Comment: Is still doesn't remove the RequiredFieldValidator.

Comment: <label id="lblLast_Name">
                        Last Name<span style="color: red;">*</span>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_tbLast_Name" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbLast_Name"
                            ErrorMessage="Last Name is Required" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbLast_Name" runat="server" MaxLength="30" CssClass="medium" />